# How to position animated SVG behind Foundation 6 element?

Tags: css, svg, grid, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm wondering if there is a way to use the Foundation grid, but then also add another element that is larger than the columns/rows in front or behind other elements. The large object is sort of part of the background, but it's an animated svg, so I can't just set it as a background.

There are two examples in the CodePen. The first(top) one is the one with the Foundation grid that I am trying to add this large, white, mostly transparent, svg circle to. The second(bottom) example is without the Foundation grid but displays the background circle (#bg-circle) as it should be.

I thought there might be some way to do it with a z-index, but I had no luck with it.

[See the CodePen here](http://codepen.io/mrseanbaines/pen/dOdoEy)

```html
<!-- See the CodePen -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Animate your SVG** and set it as a background

***The important content for your question:*** Here is a link to a youtube tutorial showing how to create an animate an SVG image file with adobe illustrator (but it doesn't have to be done that way, just a good example of using animation):

[youtube link tut on svg file creation and animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lmFMsrLgwM)

***And here is the Mozilla documentation on animation with example*** using the `animateTransform` element:

[Mozilla SVG animateTransform documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform)

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="120" height="120"  viewBox="0 0 120 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

    <polygon points="60,30 90,90 30,90">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="rotate"
                          from="0 60 70"
                          to="360 60 70"
                          dur="10s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </polygon>
</svg>
```

Placing an SVG image as background is easy enough:

[codepen using callout with svg background-image](http://codepen.io/chris0/pen/ZBozNX)

Here is some HTML and CSS as an example:

```
<div class="svgEx marg">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">Some text here.</div>
      <div class="small-4 large-4 columns">Some more text here.</div>
      <div class="small-6 large-4 columns">Even more text here.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">Some text here.</div>
      <div class="small-4 large-4 columns">Some more text here.</div>
      <div class="small-6 large-4 columns">Even more text here.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">Some text here.</div>
      <div class="small-4 large-4 columns">Some more text here.</div>
      <div class="small-6 large-4 columns">Even more text here.</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

css:

```
.svgEx {
  background: url(https://ohdoylerules.com/content/images/css3.svg) no-repeat center center;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.marg { padding: 100px 0;}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't know you could animate in HTML!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to place an SVG as a background, set a larger container and then overlay foundation's grid system on it. for example:

HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <svg>...</svg>
</div>

<div id="row-container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="columns ..."></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And The CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#row-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Okay, sweet. That put it in the right position. But now the top section shrinks to fit the relative container. How do I get the original container back to setting the height based on its contents? Maybe not the best description. See the codepen: http://codepen.io/mrseanbaines/pen/dOdoEy

Comment: you should give them both the desired height: 100% / 100vh